# tesseract 2.x - using multiple fonts at the same time

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have succesfully trained tesseract 2.x to recognize a few specific fonts. However, it seems that I can't make tesseract to recognize all of those fonts at the same time - i.e. source image contains all of them. Currently, only one set of tesseract data can be put into tessdata folder (i.e. one set with one trained font).

I know that tesseract 3.x handles correctly multiple fonts - however, I can't upgrade, since there's no decent binding to .NET, that has same features as .NET binding of version 2.x.

Also, I would like to avoid doing all the preprocessing and OCR itself several times, for each font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Tesseract 2.0x, a language data pack can recognize multiple fonts. Did you [cluster](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract2) your training files?

There are a couple excellent .NET wrapper for Tesseract 3.01. Check its [AddOn](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/AddOns) page for more info.

Comment: There is only one .NET wrapper for tesseract 3 (known to me), and that one has very bad quality - doing OCR using default tessdata will produce very bad results. However, the biggest issue is that doing such OCR will take about 10-20x more time than .NET wrapper of tesseract 2.

And about clustering - I've missed that one. I thought I can't mix fonts within the clustering. Instead I can't mix fonts within one training image.